# TableView in a TableViewController, reload data, and indexPathForSelectedRow don't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

Did a lot of research about my problem before deciding to ask for your help. Hope you'll be able to help

I have a `tableView` inside a `ViewController` and I am not able to reload data

`[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]row]` always returns **`0`**

I thing the two problems are linked, I just don't really know why. Here is my code:

`.h` file

```
@interface IITableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *blackView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

The `blackView` is the reason why I have chosen a `ViewController` instead of a `TableViewController`, the more you scroll, the darker it gets.

This is how my storyboard is set:
The "View" is linked to my `blackView` and the "Table View" to my `tableView`, my `blackView` is behind the `tableView`.

Here is the rest of the code:

viewWillApear

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.tableView reloadData];
...
```

numberOfSectionsInTableView

```
return 2;
```

numberOfRowsInSection

```
if (section==0) {
        return 1;
    } 
else {
        return self.dreams.count;
    }
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {       
    IIEntryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TitleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ...
    return cell;
}
else {
    IIEntryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EveryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ...
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[indexPath row]);
    return cell;
}
```

Everything is well displayed, my NSLog returns the right cell number.

prepareForSegue

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetails"]) {

    IIDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.dreamEntry = [self.dreams objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]row]);

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
```

`self.dreams` is a `NSArray` where my data is stored

The thing is that here the `NSLog` always returns **`0`**

And when I come back on this `View Controller` my data is not reloaded (despite the changes made in the datasource which is Sqlite by the way, I have to rebuild the app for the changes to appear correctly)

My segue is triggered in CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetails" sender:self];
```

Comment: It sounds like the `tableView` property on your controller is nil. Did you make sure to connect the table view to that outlet in your storyboard?

Comment: I am nearly shure, plus if I add
`NSLog(@"%@",self.tableView);`
I get this
<UITableView: 0x9a2b400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8c6d0c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c6bd70>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: How do you trigger the segue?  From `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` ?  If so, can you show that method.  It is likely that the selected row has been cleared, as you are getting 0

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - this method should just return cells to display in the table, but this will explain why your selectedRow is 0 - You haven't selected a row.  Have you perhaps linked the segue to the prototype cell in your storyboard?

Comment: If there is no selected row, your NSLog should return 0.

Comment: As Paulw11 said, it makes no sense to call performSegue inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. That should give you some warning messages in the console, and your table view should disappear almost immediately after it appears. Is that What you're seeing? You need to show the preformSegue method in context, not just as an isolated line of code. In any case, you should be calling performSegue in didSelectRowAtIndexPath instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues.  Check out the NSLog statement

```
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]row]);
```

it should be .row

```
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]);
```

and check in viewWillAppear if the tableView is not nil

Comment: It does not change anything, and my tableView is not nil :/

Comment: What if you comment out the [self.tableView reloadData]; in prepare for segue.  What is the reason actually to have it there?

Comment: Is the cell actually selected when you are calling pefromSegue?

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually triggering performSegue

Comment: I call performSegue in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, (I edited my post)
Sorry for the second [self.tavleView reloadData], I can totally comment it out, I was making some test and forgot to remove it

Comment: When you commented out the reloadData did that help?  Also can you show exactly where you call the performSegue in cellForRow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks guys, indeed the problem was that I didn't triggered the performSegue in the proper method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetails" sender:self];

}
```

With this code it works perfectly.
Now I guess the two problems are not linked but would you have an idea about reloadData?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I guess the two problems are not linked but would you have an idea about reloadData?

May be you didn't set dataSource for table?

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Indeed I did not, I set the delegate but not the dataSource.
Sadly it did not change anything, but if I get my data in the viewWillAppear and not in the viewDidLoad method, it works, is that all right?